# Apache Tomcat: can I use the same table for username, passwords and roles for authentication?

Tags: tomcat, authentication

I'm developing a webapp using Apache Tomcat. I was wondering if it was possible to store usernames, passwords and roles all in a table (I don't understand why I should create another table just to store the roles of users). The definition of the Real would be something like:

```
<Context>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
        driverName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        connectionURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/site"
        connectionName="postgres" connectionPassword="pass"
        userTable="user" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password"
        userRoleTable="user" roleNameCol="role" />

</Context>
```

I mean, according to the Entity–relationship model, wouldn't "username", "password" and "role" be all attributes of the same entity called "user"?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, role belongs to the entity user, but it's a N:1 relationship. A user can have several roles.